# Nested Order By Query show different result on different machine

Tags: mysql

I have query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT 1 AS a,1 AS b
       UNION
       SELECT 2 AS a,1 AS b
       UNION
       SELECT 3 AS a,2 AS b
       UNION
       SELECT 3 AS a,1 AS b
    ) b ORDER BY b.b DESC
) c
```

It's show different result on different machine,

On Machine A :

```
A  |  B
--------
3  |  2
1  |  1
2  |  1
3  |  1
```

On Machine B :

```
A  |  B
--------
1  |  1
2  |  1
3  |  2
3  |  1
```

I'm expecting all machine will get result like machine A. How can it happen ? Is there any setting on mysql server to make all machine to get result like machine A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner `ORDER BY` is meaningless as you have written it, and only an `ORDER BY` on the outer query will be honored.  In addition, I don't even see the point of the subquery, so just use this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS a, 1 AS b
    UNION
    SELECT 2, 1
    UNION
    SELECT 3, 2
    UNION
    SELECT 3, 1
) t
ORDER BY b DESC;
```

SQL tables are modeled after unordered sets of records, and generally have no internal order.  The inner `ORDER BY` you were doing does not "stick," and MySQL is free to return any order it wants in the outer query since you did not use `ORDER BY` there.